# CSS margin-top issue on different screen

Tags: jquery, css

This is my javascript code:

```
height = jQuery(window).height(); 
if (height < 700) { 
    jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", "100px");     
} else if (height >= 700 && height < 800 ) {
    jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", "160px");
}else{
    jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", "220px");
}
```

this is the html part

```
<h1 class="page-title">My Header</h1>
```

What I want to achieve is to somehow display that margin top proportionally. For instance: How do I know for window.height = 890 which will be the margin-top value for my class page-title ? What is the trick to solve that? thx.

Comment: Why you don't use media query?

Comment: because it is not about the resolution, its about the height. for instance for height 600 I shout put margin-top: 100px; for 660 I should put 110, for 700 i should put 680 ..... I do not want do it for every type of height manually.

Comment: can you place code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I do not know how do i reflect the height for all of the screens....

Comment: @HarshSanghani see my answer for a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is `page-title`, not `.page-title`. So you have to change your HTML code to:

```
<h1 class="page-title">My Header</h1>
```

The dot is only the identifier for class.

**Edit:** 
After your correction, your code works well. The code is executed only one times after page loading. I think you want to adjust it every time your window sizes changes. So i created a function:

```
function fixMargin() {
    height = jQuery(window).height();
    if (height < 700) {
        jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", "100px");
    } else if (height >= 700 && height < 800) {
        jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", "160px");
    } else {
        jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", "220px");
    }
}
```

witch is called every time the window size changes:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    fixMargin();
});
```

See the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avqoran9/

**Edit 2**

```
<h1 class="page-title" style="margin-top: 7%">My Header</h1>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zeLdapnx/

Comment: I am sorry it was a copy paste mistake, I updated my post.

Comment: You did a function for it. but that is not what I asked. what happends if the height is  820 or is 830 or is 720 or is 940, how do i know for every height what value should i put for margin-top. I asked is there a way to do it automatically

Comment: Ok, you want it dynamically. Why you don't use % instead of px?

Comment: @Chester trigger it `}).resize();` or `}).trigger('resize');`

Comment: @Christoph post me an answer with %  please

Comment: @Jai can u give me an example ?

Comment: @Chester see edit 2. Or do i misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming max top margin of 220 and minimum of 100 that gives us a difference of 120

Assuming min height is 600 and max is 900

This means that each pixel of height adds 0.4 pixels of top margin.

So we have the following function:

```
function fixMargin() {
   height = jQuery(window).height();

   var minMargin = 100;
   var maxMargin = 220;

   var differenceMargin = maxMargin - minMargin;

   var minHeight = 600;
   var maxHeight = 900;

   var calc = maxHeight - minHeight ;

   var adjuster = differenceMargin/calc;

   var differenceH = height - minHeight ;

   var marginTop = math.round(differenceH * adjuster);

   jQuery(".page-title").css("margin-top", marginTop);
}
```

I will stress this is not tested but it's close I think